# HTTP Get Request using Boost Asio C++

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new to C++ and Boost Asio, I wanted to use Boost Asio to create a simple HTTP Get request to a website having oAthn2 (bearer token) in my program but it doesn't work and I don't know why, I have tried to libCurl and separate Http request in Clion and they worked well without any problems.

```
#include "netCommon/net_Common.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace boost;
typedef asio::ip::tcp ip;



int main() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    asio::io_service ios;
    //The website
    std::string host_name = "api-fxpractice.oanda.com";
    std::string port = "443";
    //resolve DNS
    ip::resolver resolver_dns(ios);

    ip::resolver::query query_dns(host_name,port,asio::ip::tcp::resolver::numeric_service);

    ip::resolver::iterator it = resolver_dns.resolve(query_dns,ec);
    //Create a socket
    ip::socket sock(ios);
    //Connect to endpoint
    asio::connect(sock,it);
    if (ec){
        std::cout << " Failed to connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        return ec.value();
    }
    std::cout << "Connected successfully !!! " << std::endl;
    if (sock.is_open()) {
        //Create a stream buffer
        std::stringstream request_stream;
        request_stream << "GET https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                                              "Authorization: Bearer <my token>\r\n"
                                              "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        //Tried to change to Host: https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com, doesn't work either
        const auto request = request_stream.str();
        asio::write(sock, asio::buffer(request));
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
        size_t bytes = sock.available();
        if (bytes > 0) {
            std::vector<char> vBuffer(bytes);
            std::cout << "Have something to read !" << std::endl;
            asio::read(sock, asio::buffer(vBuffer));
            for (auto c: vBuffer) {
                std::cout << c;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's connected to the site but I can't get any data.
It keeps sending me either "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" or "The plain HTTP request ... send to HTTPS port"
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. :(
thank you guys so much.

Comment: I think you should use Boost Beast

Comment: If you insist on not using the beast, I will help you to correct this code

Comment: The HTTP itself works if you get the 400 Bad request. I would say you should use SSL instead of the plain HTTP. Take a look of the `boost::asio::ssl::stream`.